# scp kept getting disrupted

Tags: ssh, scp

I am copying a file from my local windows machine to a remote server running Ubuntu with `scp -v *source* *dest*`. However in the process I am constantly getting this chain of disruptions

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: rekeying in progress
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:xQbbaXvdoB3vvG1+EeyKRUxzgxxevp8XKuPBZAj/hHs
debug1: ssh_set_newkeys: rekeying out, input 505196 bytes 17047 blocks, output 3221029324 bytes 134202954 blocks
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: dequeue packet: 94
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: ssh_set_newkeys: rekeying in, input 505208 bytes 17048 blocks, output 3221045728 bytes 2050 blocks
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
```

So the file transfer will be stopped, then this message pops out, and it resumes again afterwards. Eventually the transfer will just be terminated after a while. I have checked online but it doesn't seem like this is a common problem and I am at a loss, any help would be appreciated.